# QT4 Linux will not "make" because of undefined reference to Main . What is wrong?

Tags: qt4.6

I am using Linux 10.10. Trying to use QT4 as I would like to avoid alternative IDEs and languages. I can not get past the $ make
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o slider     -L/usr/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.

No matter what I do, I searched the manual but found it referencing more Windows stuff than Linux. It is so obscure that my level of frustration leads me to ask one more time. I really do not want to go to Oracle's stuff. Can someone help?

Comment: Is this the build of Qt failing or your own program?

Answer (score 0):

I put together the demo file using the three sliders that change and show the values in the spin box. I tested it in the main development area using the control "r" feature. It works fine . I then save it to a file and do the following in the directory "slider" where I stored the file: 
qmake -project
qmake
make

The results are:$

$ make
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o slider     -L/usr/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [slider] Error 1

I suspect that I do not have the correct information in either the .project file or the Makefile. However, I don't know what else to place there. The names .Ui seem suspicious but I just don't know enough to validate that. 
Thanks
Harry
Fernandina Beach, Floria